# Select word between two words

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-selectors

How can I create a function that selects everything between the words X and Y and pushes it to an array.

> By Greili - 4 Hours and 40 Minutes ago.
>   #NsShinyGiveaway
>   0 comments
>
> By ToneBob - 4 Hours and 49 Minutes ago.
>   #NsShinyGiveaway
>   0 comments
>
> By hela222 - 5 Hours and 14 Minutes ago.
>   #NsShinyGiveaway
>   sure why not? XD
>   0 comments
>
> By NovaSplitz - 5 Hours and 45 Minutes ago.
>   #NsShinyGiveaway Enjoy life off PokeHeroes buddy.
>   0 comments

Given the text above, I want to push each word after "By" and before SPACE onto an array. The result must be something like this:

```
name[0] = "Greili"
name[1] = "ToneBob"
name[2] = "hela222"
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the text of the image? Using an external image does not appear to be necessary here, it is better when the whole question (or answer) is self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var arr = str.split("By ").reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  curr && acc.push(curr.split(" ")[0]); return acc;
}, []);
```

Result:

> ["Greili", "ToneBob", "hela222", "NovaSplitz"]

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k770y3eL/)

Comment: Since you made an effort on the other recent answer, and this is not a FGITW, I'll upvote here! Aside: I wanted to gently point out that "gents" is not an ideal assumption on your last answer, but you deleted the post `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer thanks! And yup, correct on all accounts. FWIW I will be back when the OP responds with what the error is with the SQL query. Better to not that answer with trail of comments not helping the OP at this time.

Comment: Wizard! Thank you very much! Worked perfectly for my necessity!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a regular expression:

```
var regex = /By ([^\s]+)\s/g;
var s = 'string to search goes here';
var names = [];
var result;
do {
    result = regex.exec(s);
    if (result) {
        names.push(result[1]);
    }
} while (result);
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wxcdk3po/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I see the word you want is always the second word, so that's an easier way of solving the problem. You could split the string on each space, and then you have an array of words, where the word at index 1 is the name you want. Then add each name to a new array.

```
var words = "By Greili ...".split(" ");
var name = words[1]; // "Greili"
var namesArray = [];
namesArray.push(name);
```

You'd need to do that for each of your comment strings, in a loop.